# WebSphere 6.1 generational gc default nursery size limit

Tags: memory-management, websphere

By default the nursery is supposed to be 25% of the heap, we have the initial heap size set to 1GB.  With verbose gc on, we see that our nursery is sized at 55-60MB.  We have forced the size using `-Xmns256M -Xmnx512M`.  Shouldn't this happen automatically?

Answer (score 5):

According to this technote:

> Over time the Nursery space tunes itself according to the volume of
>   objects being moved from one region to the other, effectively reaching
>   an optimal value where the reserved space is sized to only accommodate
>   the volume of objects being copied.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21509538&myns=swgws&mynp=OCSSEQTP&mync=R

So it sounds like the nursery isn't going to pre-allocate the entire 25% but instead grow as needed with a cap at 25%.